# How to make a parent class return a type which can match subtypes?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

How to define return type in a parent class such that it matches child instance class?

In the example below, the echo function needs to be defined such that it returns an object of the child class which calls this.

```scala
trait A[T] {
  def echo(a: T): T
}

class B extends A[B] {
  override def echo(x: B):B = x
}

class C extends B {
  def repeat(x: B): B = echo(x)
}

val b = new B()
val c = new C()

// Fails with error value repeat is not a member of B
c.repeat(b).repeat(b) 

// Compilation error
// Found:    B
// Required: D
class D extends B {
  def repeat(x: B): D = echo(x)
}
}
```

Comment: This is a FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you trace your call chain, you'll see that `c.repeat(b)` returns instance of `b:B` that obviously doesn't have the `repeat` method, which is defined in `C`.

In other words, in your code, `b.echo(x:B)` returns `x`, not `this`!

Perhaps you wanted to return `this` from `C.repeat`? This should work:

```scala
class C extends B {
  def repeat(x: B): C = {
    echo(x)
    this
  }
}

val b = new B()
val c = new C()

c.repeat(b).repeat(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Aivean mentioned, your method `repeat` is defined on the class `C` and returns an instance of its parent class `B`, which doesn't have the `repeat` method.

So you cannot call repeat twice like do:

```
val tmpB = c.repeat(b) // tmpB is an instance of B
tmpB.repeat(b)         // fail cuz B has no "repeat" method
```

That's that.

---

Now to answer the main question: "How to make a parent class return a type which can match subtypes?"

Same as you did with trait A, but add constraint on its argument type so that T must be an A:

```
trait A[T<:A[T]]
class B extends A[B]
```

Read more about "F-bounded polymorphism" in this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699765/1206998